# Set sequelizerc config.js with values from azure keyvault - node + typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, sequelize.js, azure-keyvault

Stack of my BE: Nodejs + typescript, sequelize, Azure keyvault has all the secrets for dbConfig.

I have `"type": "module"` in the package.json of my project, hence `module.exports` is not an option (I saw one post saying that could be the solution).

How my `db.config.ts` file looks right now.

```
import fetchSecrets from "./secrets.js";

let dbConfigs: any = {};
export const dbConfig = async () => {
  try {
    const dbDetails = await fetchSecrets("some_str"); //I have to use this way as it fetches secrets from Azure keyvault 
                                                      //and need to wait for that to be completed before proceeding further with DB connection

    const dbConfig = global.Secrets?.dbConfig;
    dbConfigs = {
      username: dbConfig?.DB_USERNAME,
      password: dbConfig?.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: dbConfig?.DB_NAME,
      host: dbConfig?.DB_HOST,
      port: dbConfig?.DB_PORT,
    };
    return dbConfigs;
  } catch (e) {}
};
export default dbConfigs;
```

`.sequelizerc`

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve("dist/config", "db.config.js"),
  "models-path": path.resolve("./", "models"),
  "migrations-path": path.resolve("./", "migrations"),
};
```

And when I run `db:migrate` script it does not work as `sequelizerc` expects configs to be returned in a certain way, which I am not able to return yet.

Error that I am seeing:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.21.3, CLI: 6.6.1, ORM: 6.32.1]

Loaded configuration file "dist/config/db.config.js".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
```

I did try to search but no luck so far. Thought of writing a `config.json` after fetching the secrets, it is definitely is not a good practice and maybe prohibited post deployment.

Need some insights on what is the best way to achieve this. Anyone who has resolved this one before? If there is something existing that I missed, let me know.

Thanks